# Apache Spark Configuration in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark in my Scala application. The problem is that the application is using all CPU cores permanently(with avg of %95). I even tried to set spark.cores.max to 1 but it did not seem to help. My application is running in local (has 4 CPU cores). What might be the problem? Here are the versions and the code I used for creating Spark Configuration.

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
   .setAppName("MyApp")
   .setMaster("local[4]")
   .set("spark.cores.max", "1")
```

scala version: 2.11.12
spark version: 2.3.0

Comment: `local[4]` means use **4** CPUs, maybe `local[1]` is what you want?

Comment: I thought local[4] meant, Spark can use 4 different Threads. Then, I wanted all 4 threads to work on a single CPU core.

Comment: By the way making it local[1] did not change anything.

Comment: Maybe the excessive usage comes from GC? or other **Spark** programs running concurrently? Or maybe the value is being overwritten somehwere else? To be honest, it is hard to tell without more information, but `master[1]` SHOULD just use one CPU and it should be the option with highest priority.